# Reading external token in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, bearer-token, django-rest-auth

I am calling Django API from .NET API. I am passing a validated Bearer token (JWT) in the header. I am not able to read the token from the header in Django API. I am using only functional API views. The users, models and db is managed in .NET only. Why is Django stripping my token in the header? How to enable secured token reading in Django Functional API?

Comment: what key are you using to send the token?

Comment: Are you using Apache? It may be stripping the Authorization header

Comment: The key is 'Authorization'. I am not using Apache server. I checked that as well. Currently just checking on localhost only.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613315/accessing-request-headers-on-django-python

Comment: I tried both the links also, long back :( Nothing worked for me. Do I need to add any specific settings?